# Confusion entre « de » et « de la »

Tags: grammaire, articles

Dans un de mes mails reçus, je vois cette phrase:

> Modifications des conditions de l'affichage

La question spécifique est pourquoi c'est **de l'affichage** et non pas **d'affichage**

Comment: Il faudrait plus de contexte.

Answer (score 1):

C'est sensiblement la même chose, les deux sont quasiment interchangeables.

Quand on utiliser "*du/de la/de l'* " au lieu de "*de/d'* ", on se réfère normalement à quelque chose de plus concret (un objet en particulier plutôt que tous de façon générale) mais il est fréquent de parler d'un objet pour parler de tous, par extension.

Comment: On pourrait remplace *concret* par *spécifique*, la définitude n'a rien à voir avec être concret : *la liberté* fonctionne avec le déterminant défini sans être concret pour autant...

Answer (score -1):

En fait, Modifications des conditions de l'affichage sans rien derrière est incorrect. La phrase est incomplète : en introduisant l'article défini, on sous-entend une définition de l'affichage. Par exemple Modification des conditions de l'affichage des résultats des examens. Par contre, la phrase ci-dessus serait plus correcte réécrite ainsi : Modifications des conditions d'affichage. Car il s'agit de l'affichage en général, dans ce bâtiment (par exemple).

Comment: « Modifications des conditions de l'affichage » n'est pas incorrect. Il n'y a pas de problème grammatical et il n'y a pas vraiment de problème de compréhension, cette phrase apparaissant forcément dans un contexte où l'interlocuteur ou le lecteur savent de quel affichage il s'agit. L'expression « [dégradation des termes de l'échange](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9gradation_des_termes_de_l'%C3%A9change) » est un exemple connu qui reprend ce schéma.